# String.Format Not Aligning Correctly using ToShortDateString and String

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This Line

```
TitleDate = string.Format("Date: {0, -10}  Title: {1, 10}" ,c.Date.ToShortDateString() ,c.Title)
```

Is Showing:

```
Date: 8/26/2007 Title: A Title
Date: 10/13/2011 Title: A Title
Date: 11/11/2012 Title: A Title
Date: 3/1/2001 Title: A Title
```

I am trying for

```
Date: 8/26/2007  Title: A Title
Date: 10/13/2011 Title: A Title
Date: 11/11/2012 Title: A Title
Date: 3/1/2001   Title: A Title
```

These values are being displayed in the text field of a treeview

Comment: may I ask why don't you use table for this?

Comment: They are being displayed in the text field of a treeview

Comment: If they're rendered by the browser, it will remove excess whitespace by default e.g. '2007<space><space>Title' will become '2007<space>Title'. If this is your issue then you could put the <pre> tag in your text.

Comment: @StevieB - this is likely the reason - consider posting as an answer... One would have to use fixed width font and `&nbsp;` instead of space to align text in HTML (or `white-space:pre;` style)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method

There are three possibilities, your date string might have 8,9 or 10 character.So here is a possible (I guess), but not elegant solution:

```
string date = c.Date.ToShortDateString();
int lenght = date.Length;
int whiteSpace = 0;
switch (length)
        {
            case 8:
                whitespace = 6;
                break;
            case 9:
                whitespace = 5;
                break;
            case 10:
                whitespace = 4;
                break;
        }

TitleDate = string.Format("Date: {0}  Title: {1}" ,date.PadRight(whiteSpace,' '), c.Title);
TitleDate = TitleDate.Replace(" ","&nbsp");
```

Or you can use custom [DateTime Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and make it more elegant:

```
TitleDate = string.Format("Date: {0}  Title: {1}" ,c.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") ,c.Title)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're seeing this issue when the string is being rendered in a browser.

By default, browsers will replace multiple whitespace characters with a single whitespace e.g. a tab followed by two spaces will be rendered as if there were only one space present.

The browser must be informed that you want to keep all whitespace in this string.

For example you could replace all space characters in the string to be rendered with `&nbsp;`

```
TitleDate = string.Format("Date: {0, -10}  Title: {1, 10}" ,c.Date.ToShortDateString(), c.Title);
TitleDate.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Also, as @AlexeiLevenkov notes in the comments you must ensure that the text is rendered using a fixed width font.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML formation for it.
Pass a class setting with CSS will be a good idea